# Replace null values with the former row's value

Tags: null, hana

Have a table with Exchange rates, but some days have null values. For the days with null values, I want to pick the earlier day's exchange rate. Any help?

[image: Exchange rate Table]

Answer (score 0):

I used [SQL row_number() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/hana-database-sqlscript-row_number-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) with partition by clause as follows

```
declare i_date date = '20170105';
declare i_kurst varchar(1) = 'M';
declare i_fcurr varchar(5) = 'LKR';
declare i_tcurr varchar(5) = 'USD';

select top 1
    rate, row_number() over (partition by kurst, fcurr, tcurr order by maindate desc) as rn
from ExchangeRates
where maindate <= :i_date
and kurst = :i_kurst
and fcurr = :i_fcurr
and tcurr = :i_tcurr;
```

You can place this code in a UDF (user-defined function) and use it by passing those parameters required for reading exchange rates like date, source and target currencies, etc.

By the way, an easier way is returning top 1 rate in a sorted result set by date as follows

```
select top 1 rate
from ExchangeRates
where maindate <= :i_date
and kurst = :i_kurst
and fcurr = :i_fcurr
and tcurr = :i_tcurr
order by maindate desc;
```

This is how you can encapsulate this SQLScript into a UDF user-defined SQL function on HANA database. Here is an other HANA DB [SQL function](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/sql-string-replicate-function-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) code sample for reference to parameters and syntax

```
create function read_exchange_rate (
    i_date date,
    i_kurst varchar(4),
    i_fcurr varchar(5),
    i_tcurr varchar(5)
) returns rate decimal(9,5)
as
begin

select top 1 rate into "RATE"
from ExchangeRates
where maindate <= :i_date
and kurst = :i_kurst
and fcurr = :i_fcurr
and tcurr = :i_tcurr
order by maindate desc;

end;
```

And you can use this function as follows

```
select read_exchange_rate('20170106','M','LKR','USD') from dummy;
```

I think it is important to note here; I guess you already know exchange rates are stored in TCURR table in SAP. There the dates are stored as inverted date format. So if you need to [convert inverted date](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/convert-inverted-date-in-hana-database-using-sqlscript.aspx) to normal date format, you can refer to given tutorial

Inserting missing date records is a little bit more complex then selecting values. To determine missing dates, I used a [numbers table function](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-numbers-table-function-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) on HANA database which I converted to a dates table easily.

select * from Numbers_Table(365)

Above SQL will return a table with numbers starting from 1 to 365 that can be used to calculate days for a whole year

Please check following code, after you create the numbers function on your HANA database
It identifies missing dates starting from 1st of Jan within 12 days period for given parameters 
Then inserts new exchange rate records for those missing days with the rate which is the most closest previous not null exchange rate value

```
declare i_startdate date = '20170101';
declare i_kurst varchar(1) = 'M';
declare i_fcurr varchar(5) = 'LKR';
declare i_tcurr varchar(5) = 'USD';

insert into ExchangeRates (
    maindate, kurst, fcurr, tcurr, rate
)
select 
    add_days(i_startdate,rownum-1) dt,
    :i_kurst,
    :i_fcurr,
    :i_tcurr,
    read_exchange_rate(
        add_days(i_startdate,rownum-1),
        :i_kurst,
        :i_fcurr,
        :i_tcurr
    ) as newrate
from Numbers_Table(12) as nt
left join ExchangeRates r
    on r.maindate = add_days(i_startdate,rownum-1)
    and r. kurst = :i_kurst
    and fcurr = :i_fcurr
    and tcurr = :i_tcurr
where r.maindate is null;
```

I hope it helps,